# Android ACTION_SEND with special file name

Tags: android, android-intent, share, send

I used to use following code for sharing file from my app:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(fPath)));
shareIntent.setType(fType);
mActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "SHARE"));
```

It usually works fine but recently I noticed that it will generate "No apps can perform this action" if there is special characters in the file name, e.g. "=" or Chinese/Japanese characters.

I tried to use recommended "FileProvider" to serve my file and pass a content uri to the sender. However, not all of the target applications can support content uri well, e.g. Wechat/EsfileManager etc.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

try using **URLEncoder** for **fileName** Only:

```
              /* your file path */
fpath =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + URLEncoder.encode(fileName);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(fPath)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, although I have doubt but I still tried to make sure that it does not work.